# How can I define a user screen when using ADT 21?

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I updated my ADT to 21 last night, but then I found that in the ADT XML Overlay tool, I can't define a custom screen(1024*768, mdpi). Could you help me?

Comment: Give the link of the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Update your ADT to version 21.

**In Older Version each time you have to set `Add Custom` Screen if you want custom Device Configurations.**

In ADT21 Oversion you can get this thing done by

> **open `AVD Manager`, u can define your custom screen in `"Device Definition"`**

**Alternative (Much Easier approach)**

> in Newest Version you Don't Need to Set Custom Device
>   Configurations from the above Suggestion as much easier way is available for it. you >Just Have to Make Emulator With your Device 
>   Configurations and after you will see those Configurations with
>   Emulator Name Inside `Graphical Layout` of XML

like after Created my Emulator of Nexus7 Emulator with Android 4.2 with Name as "Nexus7_Android_4.2" i will get this Device Configuration in Graphical Layout of xml automatically.

Below is the Screen Shot of it.

[image]

Hope it will Help you.

Comment: It works！ Thanks！ Open the AVD Manager, u can define your custom screen in "Device Definition" tag