# Preview Nexus 10 layout on Eclipse with ADT R21

Tags: android, layout, adt

For some reason, after updating the ADT to R21, I cannot preview my layout on any type of size like I could before :

[image: Nexus 10 cannot be found here]

So, I declared a new Android Virtual Device by using the AVD manager and there, I can't found anything that could look like a Nexus 10 resolution :

[image]

Is anyone having the same trouble ? How can I preview a Nexus 10 layout with the cool "Preview All screens" feature ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Same question as here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13656793/how-can-i-define-a-user-screen-when-using-adt-21

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to create a new 'Device Definition' for the Nexus 10 and populate it with the information regarding resolution, ram etc for that device.  You can find the 'Device Definition' tab in the Android Virtual Device Manager.  Once you create the new device definition, it will appear as an option in the 'Create New Android Device (AVD)' dialog box.

Good luck!

Note: I am running Mac OS X 10.8.2 and Eclipse ADT v21

<strike>I tried to add an image here, but I need at least 10 reputation.  Sorry.</strike>

[image: AVD Manager]